# What software can be used to create logic from datasets?

Tags: windows, data-analysis, microsoft-excel, csv

I need a software that can import a dataset (excel/CSV table) and I can write formulas/create a workflow logic to export into another (excel/CSV) table.

I need this software to be able to be deployed so I can program a logic for different people with different table formats.

Is there such software out there? I looked into Microsoft Power Query for Excel but it doesn't seem like anything different than if I wrote the formulas in Excel itself. [Safe Software's FME](https://www.safe.com/solutions/for-data-types/non-spatial/) offers something similar that I need but it has a whole bunch of other features and the price is far too great for a server license.